# how to insert into has_many association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so, ive this weird issue, it seems that rails wont allow insertion through has_many association in my models.

basically when i do

```
q = Question.first
u = User.first
u.views.create(question_id: q.id)
```

rails performs the transaction but for some reason it rolls it back

[image]

here is the models

```
class View < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user

  validates :viewer_id, presence: true
  validates :question_id, presence: true
end
```

Question and User model work as expected, but for some reason this happens, thanks for your answer

**edit**

i have solved this issue with doing it like so

```
  def view(question)
    v = View.new(viewer_id: id)
    v.update_attribute :question_id, question.id
  end
```

but still not happy with the implementation

Comment: Have you tried running `u.views.create!(question_id: q.id)` with an exclamation point (it will tell you why the validations fail). It's odd because both question and viewer id are filled in and those are the only validations...

Comment: you shouldn't need to use `validates` on `viewer_id` and `question_id` as `belong_to` is not optional by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you after this code print error?

```
q = Question.first
u = User.first
u.views.create(question_id: q.id)
```

Just add `p u.errors.full_messages`

I think you will see sth like this `User must be present` (validation error)

It's because `belongs_to :user` don't have link on `viewer` (`viewer_id` in db/schema right?)

It must be like this `belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "viewer_id"` (or maybe `primary_key`, sory, I forgot the different between primary_key and foreign_key)

In you case `update_attribute` just skip validations.